# Displaying total votes count with thumbs_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, voting

I am trying to display total votes cast on a post with thumbs_up gem but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code

```
    def vote_up
    begin
      post = Post.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(post)
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:sucess] = "You have voted successfully"
      @votes_total = post.votes_for
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = "You have already voted for this one"
    end

  end
```

In the view :-

```
<%="Total votes = #{@votes_total}"%>
```

I get the flash message "You have voted successfully" but my votes count are not getting displayed.

This is what I have in my log files :-

> [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE
>   "votes"."voteable_id" = 12 AND "votes"."voteable_type" = 'Post' AND
>   "votes"."vote" = 't'[0m 0

**--- Update ---**

Update my post controller with this code :-

```
def vote_up
    begin
      post = Post.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(post)
      @votes_total = post.votes_for
      render :template => "home/index"
      flash[:sucess] = "You have voted successfully"

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = "You have already voted for this one"
    end

  end
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not display because you are redirecting. When redirecting you are basically doing a new request and the instance variables of the former request won't be available anymore. Flash does work, because it uses the `session`. Solution: either set `@votes_total` in the action you are redirecting to or use `render` instead of `redirect_to`.

Comment: I am not able to see even if I do render :template => "home/index"

Comment: Note that you have to put `@votes_total = post.votes_for` above `render ...`

Comment: This should work... You do see `Total votes =` in your view? What happens if you redirect to `home/index` and add `@votes_total = post.votes_for` to the index action of your home controller?

Comment: I have defined post = Post.find(params[:id]) in PostsController and index action is in HomeController wont it be a issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6604/discussion-between-dev-r-and-mischa)

Comment: Just ot add if I do @post.votes_count in the console I am getting the right number. Also as you said in your earlier message I am able to see Total votes = in the view, I am also able to see the vote count if  in the index view. Still not sure how to get it in _post.html.erb

Comment: From the code you show here it should work... sorry but I don't know how to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

> @votes_total

to the

> @post.votes_for or corresponding equivalent

in the view.

Comment: unrecognized method votes_for is the error which I get by doing this